# ¿Como podria simplificar este codigo?

Tags: python, class, python-3.7, lógica

hace poco comencé a aprender Python por mi cuenta y tengo muchos problemas con las proposiciones lógicas, espero alguien puede ayudarme y decirme como podría simplificar el código que les presento a continuación:

```
class Triangulo:
def __init__(self, lado1, lado2, lado3):
    self.lado1 = lado1
    self.lado2 = lado2
    self.lado3 = lado3

def clasificacion(self):
    if self.lado1 ==  self.lado2 and self.lado1 !=  self.lado3 :
        return "Triangulo Isosceles"
    elif self.lado2 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado1:
        return "Triangulo Isosceles"
    elif self.lado1 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado2:
        return "Triangulo Isosceles"
    elif self.lado1 == self.lado2 and self.lado1 == self.lado3:
        return "Triangulo equilatero"
    elif self.lado1 != self.lado2 and self.lado1 != self.lado3:
        return "Triangulo Escaleno"
```

Para obtener un triángulo isósceles siento que es demasiado largo lo que escribí y me preguntaba si existe una manera de simplificarlo.
Especificamente esta parte:

```
    if self.lado1 ==  self.lado2 and self.lado1 !=  self.lado3 :
        return "Triangulo Isoceles"
    elif self.lado2 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado1:
        return "Triangulo Isoceles"
    elif self.lado1 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado2:
        return "Triangulo Isoceles"
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías  simplificar la comparación de forma sencilla si primero compruebas si es equilátero. Al hacer esto te evitas tener que comprobar si el tercer lado es diferente a los otros dos en el isósceles.

Por otro lado puedes usar un `else`, si no es equilátero ni isósceles te queda que sea escaleno (obviamente si es un triángulo válido):

```
if self.lado1 == self.lado2 == self.lado3:
    return "Triangulo equilatero"
elif self.lado1 == self.lado2 or self.lado1 == self.lado3 or self.lado2 == self.lado3:
    return "Triangulo Isosceles"
else:
    return "Triangulo Escaleno"
```

Las comparaciones pueden ser encadenadas de forma arbitraria:

```
if self.lado1 == self.lado2 == self.lado3:
```

es equivalente a:

```
if self.lado1 == self.lado2 and self.lado2 == self.lado3
```

---

Por si a alguien le interesa, digo que ambas expresiones son "equivalentes" y no "iguales" solamente porque el bytecode generado difiere debido a algunas operaciones extra en la pila, aunque el resultado es el mismo de cualquier forma:

> ```
> >>> import dis
>
> >>> dis.dis("0 == 0 == 0")
>   1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>               2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>               4 DUP_TOP
>               6 ROT_THREE
>               8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
>              10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
>              12 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>              14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
>              16 RETURN_VALUE
>              18 ROT_TWO
>              20 POP_TOP
>              22 RETURN_VALUE
>
> >>> dis.dis("0 == 0 and 0 == 0")
>   1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>               2 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>               4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
>               6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
>               8 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>              10 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
>              12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
>              14 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer uso de [any](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any) que básicamente verifica que en un array al menos un elemento sea True.

```
def clasificacion(self):
    if any([(self.lado1 ==  self.lado2 and self.lado1 !=  self.lado3), (self.lado2 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado1), (self.lado1 ==  self.lado3 and self.lado3 != self.lado2) ] :
        return "Triangulo Isosceles"
    elif self.lado1 == self.lado2 and self.lado1 == self.lado3:
        return "Triangulo equilatero"
    elif self.lado1 != self.lado2 and self.lado1 != self.lado3:
        return "Triangulo Escaleno"
```

Answer (score 2):

Por aportar una solución menos convencional (y no necesariamente la más recomendable), podrías hacer el siguiente truco.

Si metes los tres lados en un conjunto, ya que los conjuntos eliminan los elementos repetidos y dejan sólo los diferentes, si al final el conjunto tiene un solo elemento es que los tres lados eran iguales, si tiene dos elementos es que tenía dos iguales y uno diferente, y si tiene tres elementos, que los tres eran distintos. Por tanto:

```
def clasificacion(self):
    distintos = len(set([self.lado1, self.lado2, self.lado3]))
    if distintos == 3:
       return "Triángulo escaleno"
    if distintos == 2:
       return "Triángulo isósceles"
    if distintos == 1:
       return "Triángulo equilátero"
```

Puede quedar aún más compacto si tienes preparadas las respuestas en un diccionario, según el número de lados diferentes:

```
def clasificacion(self):
    caso = {1: "Triángulo equilátero", 2: "Triángulo isósceles", 3: "Triángulo escaleno" }
    lados_distintos = len(set([self.lado1, self.lado2, self.lado3]))
    return caso[lados_distintos]
```

Answer (score 0):

Un poquito más corta aunque básicamente es la misma idea:

```
def clasificacion(self):
    d={1:'equilátero',2:'isósceles',3:'escaleno'}
    return f'Triángulo {d[len(set([self.lado1,self.lado2,self.lado3]))]}'
```